# Zendframe work include path Error on Hosting

Tags: php, zend-framework, include, hosting

I am trying to implement oAuth using Zendframe work. The script is running great on my **localhost** whereas when i am **hosting the same files on to server** (online) it is giving me include path error. I am not figuring out what might be the problem.

Error : `Warning: require_once(Zend/Http/Client.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in`

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the path in which Zend Framework is installed to your include path:

```
set_include_path('/path/where/Zend/directory/is' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
```

The [include path](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) is where PHP searches when you include a script.

Also, it's likely that you may have to upload the Zend Framework to your hosting server, as your hosting provider may not have installed it.

Comment: @Hello, i uploaded a folder called Zend( which contains folder like bin, demos, externals, library etc..) then what might be the path i have to  set in code you mentioned..Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the location where Zend Framework exists on your local host is defined in the default include path of your PHP configuration, or you're setting some include paths specific to application environment.

Compare the output of your `get_include_path()` in development and production, to see where it goes wrong. You can add the path where the application can find the Zend files from with `set_include_path()`, eg:

```
set_include_path(
    APPLICATION_PATH.'/../library'.
    PATH_SEPARATOR.
    get_include_path()
);
```